# Lattices of $\mathbb{R}^s \ltimes_\varphi \mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices

**Edit**: Thoughts updated (22/3/2021).

I've come across with the following problem.

Let $G=\mathbb{R}^s \ltimes_\varphi \mathbb{R}^k$ where $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^s\to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{R}^k)=\mathsf{GL}(k,\mathbb{R})$ is an homomorphism such that $\mathbb{R}^k=N$ the nilradical of $G$ (i.e. $N$ is the maximal connected nilpotent normal subgroup of $G$ so that $\mathfrak{n}$ is the maximal nilpotent ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$).

If we take $\Gamma_1$ a lattice (discrete and cocompact subgroup) in $\mathbb{R}^s$ and $\Gamma_2$ a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\varphi(\Gamma_1)$ preserves $\Gamma_2$ then $\Gamma=\Gamma_1\ltimes_\varphi \Gamma_2$ is a lattice of $G$. Let us call $\Gamma$ a splittable lattice.

**Question**: Are **all** the lattices in $G=\mathbb{R}^s\ltimes_\varphi\mathbb{R}^k$ splittable lattices?

**Thoughts**: By Mostow's theorem on solvmanifolds, we have that $\Gamma\cap\mathbb{R^k}$ is lattice in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\Gamma/\Gamma\cap\mathbb{R}^k$ is a lattice in $G/\mathbb{R}^k\cong\mathbb{R}^s$.

Then we have the following exact short sequences:

$0\to N\to G \to G/N\to 0$ and

$0\to \Gamma\cap N \to \Gamma \to \Gamma/\Gamma\cap N\to 0$.

The above sequence splits and we have the inclusion of the groups below in the groups above. But I don't know if it possible to conclude that the sequence below also splits. If it helps, the group $\Gamma$ is a polycyclic group.

**Another important hypothesis is that the group $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to a Bieberbach group (so it has a finite index abelian subgroup $\Lambda$, according to First Bieberbach's Theorem)**

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\Gamma/(\Gamma \cap N)$ is a free abelian group of rank $s$, so the only question is whether there exist $s$ *commuting* elements of $\Gamma$ lifting a set of generators (e.g. for $s \leq 1$ this is automatic).

Comment: I don't understand your claim that Gamma has a finite index abelian subgroup. This is does not seem true at all since lattices are Zariski dense.

Comment: Every (group isomorphic to a) Bieberbach group of $\mathrm{Iso}({R^k})$ has a maximal abelian normal subgroup of finite index (this is the First Bieberbach Theorem)

Comment: Why is Gamma isomorphic to a Bieberbach group? Typically such groups, which are torsion-free and virtually abelian, occur inside semidirect products of the form ${\mathbb R}^d \rtimes O(d)$, and they don't have to be solvable

Comment: Yes, I think I was not clear from the beginning. The groups $\mathbb{R}^s\ltimes_{\varphi} \mathbb{R}^k$ I am working with are fundamental groups of flat solvmanifolds (which are a particular case of compact flat manifolds), so they are isomorphic to Bieberbach groups.

Comment: I'm afraid I still find this hard to follow. Take $s=1$. Can you give me an example of an action $\varphi$ on a suitable ${\mathbb R}^k$, and a lattice $\Gamma$ inside this semidirect product? Then we can see how this is virtually abelian without having to appeal to the Bieberbach theorems.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify a little. The action $\varphi$ is (in my case) multiplying by skew-symmetric matrices. For example Taking $s=1$ and $k=2$, $\varphi(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & -\sin(t) \\ \sin(t) & \cos(t) \end{pmatrix}$, and a lattice $\Gamma$ is $\frac{2\pi}{3} \mathbb{Z}\ltimes_{\varphi} P\mathbb{Z}^2$ where $P^{-1} \varphi(\frac{2\pi}{3}) P$ is an integer matrix. The subgroup $\Lambda=2\pi \mathbb{Z}\ltimes_{\varphi} P\mathbb{Z}^2$ is abelian and $\Gamma/\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}_3$